# Как оптимально из массива выбрать самые длинней строки?

Tags: php, алгоритм

Есть массив со строками:

1. `$inputArray = ["aba", "aa", "ad", "vcd", "aba"];`
2. `$inputArray = ["aa", "bbbb", "cc", "yyyy", "j"];`
3. `$inputArray = ["aaaaa", "ss", "yyyyy", "u", "ooooo"];`

**Вопрос:** Как получить массив в результате с самыми длинными строками ?

Ожидаемый результат

1. `= [aba, vcd, aba]`
2. `= ["bbbb", "yyyy"]`
3. `= ["aaaaa", "yyyyy", "ooooo"]`

Решил не очень оптимально:

На мой взгляд можно обойти без использовании функции `array_filter()` и `array_values()`.

```
function allLongestStrings(array $inputArray)
{
    if(!$inputArray)
        return [];
    $arr = [];
    $first = $inputArray[0];
    for ($i = 0, $cnt = count($inputArray); $i < $cnt; $i++)
    {
        if(strlen($inputArray[$i]) >= strlen($first))
        {
            $arr[] = $first = $inputArray[$i];
            $arr = array_filter($arr, function($v) use ($first){
                if(strlen($v) >= strlen($first))
                    return strlen($v);
            });
        }
    }
    return array_values($arr);
}

$inputArray = ["aba", "aa", "ad", "vcd", "aba"];
echo '<pre>';
print_r(allLongestStrings($inputArray)); 

$inputArray = ["aba", "eeee", "ffff", "yyyy", "o"];
print_r(allLongestStrings($inputArray)); 

$inputArray = ["abc", "eeee", "abcd", "dcd"];
print_r(allLongestStrings($inputArray));
```

Comment: В PHP нет аналога LINQ с группировкой по длине строк?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю как оптимально из массива выбрать самые длинней строки, но как вариант, чуть сокращенный:

```
function allLongestStrings(array $inputArray) {
    if(!$inputArray)
        return [];

    $maxLength = max(array_map('strlen', $inputArray));

    return array_filter($inputArray, function($v) use($maxLength){     
         return strlen($v) == $maxLength;
    });
}
```

---

Еще какой-то набросок:

```
function allLongestStrings(array $inputArray) {
    $cnt = count($inputArray);
    $output = [];
    $max = $inputArray[0];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt;  ++$i) {
        $len = strlen($inputArray[$i]);
        if ($len > $max) $max = $len;

        if (!isset($output[$len])) 
            $output[$len] = [];

        $output[$len][] = $inputArray[$i];
    }    

    return $output[$max]; 
}
```

Comment: Несколько дней назад роясь в codefights.com Наткнулся на оптимальное решение, и забыл.Вот сейчас пытаюсь вспомнить да не получается.В том решение тошно не использовались вспомогательные функции

Comment: Хотелось бы конечно посмотреть. Но уверен, что там циклы использовались. Правда map/filter - те же циклы, только засахаренные

Comment: Да еще ваш вариант возвращает индексы этих строк,а нужен чтоб начинались с нуля. Ожидаемый результат `[aba, vcd, aba]`.

Comment: Хотя ваш ответ тоже мне понравился

Comment: `Да еще ваш вариант возвращает индексы этих строк` - да вроде нет  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/378c7bcdd9dea061cb85d642a6c8c1c2c814cbf0  .А с нуля для чего? я так понимаю всё равно фильтруются данные чтоб их все и использовать, а значит foreach пойдет.....если по порядку, то тогда вместо `array_filter` надо будет обычный цикл делать складывая в новый массив.... тобишь будет `$maxLength = max(array_map('strlen', $inputArray)); $output = [];
    foreach ($inputArray as $item){
        if (strlen($item) == $maxLength){
            $output[] = $item;}
    }
    return $output;`

Comment: 'да вроде нет' Передайте пожалуйста это `['o','ee','y']`  `Array ( [1] => ee )` Результат будет с индексом 1 а не 0.А почему так ?, да вопрос такой :))).

Comment: ты просто не дописал предложение. потому что "возвращает индексы этих строк" != "возвращает строки со значением ключей в исходном массиве") А так да. Но как сделать по порядку написал выше

Comment: `2. ["bbbb", "yyyy"] ` В вопросе я все написал.Правда не словами но показал какой результат ожидаю.Спасибо за ответ.Скорее всего завтра может найду решение

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan `2. ["bbbb", "yyyy"] В вопросе я все написал.` - как это противоречит тому, что написано в ответе?)) И как это указывает на то, что индексы должны быть с нуля и по порядку?)

Comment: входной массив  ` ["aa", "bbbb", "cc", "yyyy", "j"]`, результат `["bbbb", "yyyy"]`. у значения 'bbbb' в входном массиве ключ равен 1, а в результирующем массиве ключ равен 0

Comment: из примера ясно только то, что должен получится результат `["bbbb", "yyyy"]` (что и получается в ответе). Про значения ключей там ни слова.

Comment: Для второго варианта я бы предложил накапливать максимальную длину в переменной, пока идет цикл и потом брать этот конкретный элемент.

Comment: @Mike тоже была эта мысль, только я не додумал как потом это применить. сейчас поправлю

Comment: Я сравнил скорости. splice оказались дико тормозными. раз эдак в 1000 по сравнению даже с вашим первым вариантом (тест на массиве 10к элементов длиной от 1 до 10). Ваш второй вариант в два раза быстрей первого

Comment: Я поправил свой вариант, теперь он в 1.5 раза быстрее вашего второго. отказался от splice сдвигающего элементы, оставил только отрезающий. Ну и пришлось перенумеровать массив на выходе

Comment: @Mike потому что splice надо было не в цикле использовать, а у итогового массива хвост отчекрынить. именно поэтому я размышлял как отсортировать и затем остаток удалить)) пойду смотреть ваш вариант))

Comment: @Mike мой тормозит из-за постоянного создания массива и впихивания значения по ключу. в общем из-за доп работы с массивом

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan  взгляни на вариант от **Mike**. Говорит у него сейчас побыстрее работает (что логично по причине указанной мной выше в комментарии)....... Кстати, нашел тот вариант, который показывали на codefights.com? Интересно было бы посмотреть

Comment: Я внес маленькую правку в ваш второй вариант, добавил `if($len==$max)` перед присвоением output, теперь он стал чуть чуть быстрее моего варианта :) http://ideone.com/LiEvAN  Хотя не совсем так, в зависимости от сложности входного набора и разнородности значений. На входном наборе 10к элементов, если различных по длине элементов мало (в генераторе длины от 1 до 100), то ваш быстрее, если разных длин 1000, то мой. И еще могут быть зависимости от распределения элементов по массиву, но это протестировать слишком сложно

Comment: Я только заметил твой  второй вариант.Отлично ! Но пусть оба остаются,первый тоже хорошо выглядит :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function allLongestStrings(array $input)
{
  if(!$input) return [];
  $i=count($input)-1;
  if($i==0) return $input;      // В массиве 1 элемент - вернуть его
  $len=strlen($input[$i--]);    // Длина последнего элемента
  $last=0;                      // Первый элемент для удаления
  for(;$i>=0;$i--) {            // Цикл с предпоследнего элемента
    $clen=strlen($input[$i]);
    if($clen < $len) {          // Если текущий элемент короче
      unset($input[$i]);        // Удаляем его
    } elseif($clen > $len) {    // Если длиннее
      $last=$i;                 // запоминаем его позицию - за ним все элементы короче
      $len=$clen;               // Сохраняем новую максимальную длину
    }
  }
  if($last) array_splice($input,$last+1); // Удаляем короткие элементы с конца
  return array_values($input);  // Перенумеруем оставшиеся
}
```

Comment: вот я тоже сижу сейчас думаю как splice'ом отрезать. я хотел отсортировать по длине строк и дальше сделать splice.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский После сортировки по длине порядок элементов с одной длиной будет не предсказуемым. потому что там используется qsort или его подобие, а он сортирует частями

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Кстати, вы не в курсе, как работает strlen в php. Он берет готовую длину откуда то или считает ее заново каждый раз (как это происходит в C)

Comment: Не в курРрРрсе.

Comment: Надо `array_splice($input,$i)` а не `array_splice($input,$i + 1)`. иначе пустой массив возвращает))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Блин, пока тестировал разные варианты и сюда частями переносил ошибка закралась :) И там $last даже, а не $i Кстати, если обрезание хвоста внутри цикла, оно не особо сильно замедляет. тот комментарий про 1.5 раза был с хвостовым splice внутри цикла. ввод переменной и вынос из цикла еще чуть чуть ускорило, но не сильно. Самой страшной конечно была операция удаления одного элемента со сдвигом хвоста

Comment: @АлексейШиманский http://ideone.com/sCmR8O

Answer (score 0):

По моему  хороший вариант:

```
function allLongestStrings($inputArray) {
    $longestLen = 0;
    $longestArray = [];

    foreach($inputArray as $str) {
        $len = strlen($str);

        if($len > $longestLen) {
            $longestArray = [$str];
            $longestLen = $len;
        }
        else if ($len == $longestLen) {
            $longestArray[] = $str;
        }
    }

    return $longestArray;
}
```

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Оцените.Без всяких функций,ну кроме strlen

Comment: @Mike  Как вам такой вариант ?

Comment: Ну это практически то же что у Шиманского, после его некоторой модификации. вот результаты тестов http://ideone.com/mw7oFg самое прикольное, что на ideone ваш вариант чуть чуть быстрее, а на моей машине, быстрее вариант @АлексейШиманский (итоговую версию посмотрите в моем тестовом коде) всех остальных, причем заметно быстрее. 0.1603639125824 при вашем варианте 0.2434070110321. Думаю в разных версиях php по разному реализован сборщик мусора и ваш вариант на этих версиях начинает страдать при перезаписи массива новым значением.

Comment: И да, в 1% тестов мой оказывается чуточку быстрее вашего. Видимо когда подходящие значения оказываются ближе к началу входного массива и splice отрезает больший кусок

Comment: @Mike Честно я еще не тестировал,так на взгляд прикинул.Ну раз говорите значит оно так и есть.Благодарю за участие .ваш ответ обоснованный  и достоин похвал.

Comment: Мой страдает в самом конце, когда приходится перенумеровывать элементы. Он был бы актуален, если бы надо было удалить из входного массива все короткие строки с сохранением ключей длинных строк. Да, вы погоняйте тот тест с ideone на своей версии. мне все таки очень интересно почему на моей машине такой капитальный выигрыш варианта @АлексейШиманский, при том, что очевидно он должен использовать немного больше памяти чем ваш, храня дополнительные массивы не самых длинных элементов